# Having a class for each table in the database

Tags: design-patterns, database-design

I'm creating a software for my friends library. For now I have a table in the database for books and movies, but lets say that the user would want to add cds aswell. Then I'd have to let the user create a table in the database for cds. The design so far, is to be having a class for each table in the database, with its fields, and methods for inserting and updating data in the database (c# and mysql). How would I go ahead and make a "general" class for all tables in the database, and not for each specific like I'm doing now.

I'm looking for a name on a pattern or something like that, not a complete tutorial in reply.

Thanks :)

Comment: What you're doing is good. That's basically what every ORM does. I wouldn't merge all the tables into a single object (how would you represent relations?). Have a look at opf3 (http://opf3.codeplex.com/) which is an ORM for MySQL + .NET

Comment: To merge all the tables into a single object is kind of what I'm asking for. Is there a name of pattern doing so that I can google? I represent relations in the logiclayer, dont know if this is the way to do it. In the logiclayer I  kind of puzzle together the databaselayer classes.

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo. I meant to say "I wouldn't merge.."

Comment: Ah ok :) But how would I let the user add CDs, or cartoons, and such things later on?

Comment: You can add methods for associative entities in the primary entity. A simple way is to have getters/setters for these associative entities and set the relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some patterns:

- [Single Table Inheritance](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) (what you think you want to do)
- [Class Table Inheritance](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html) (what you are doing now)
- [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html)

Comment: A disadvantage of STI is that you cannot declare your database columns as NOT NULL unless they are defined in the super class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using Map or Dictionary. In simple words using name/value pairs. But that is a pretty bad design for what you are doing. This will make things difficult for you and manage as well.

I know what you are thinking about having to write the same methods over and over again for all the tables. For that case you should be using some kind of ORM (Object Relation Mapping). For java you can use Hibernate, Toplink. NHibernate is a port of Hibernate in .Net.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that. I'm not so worried about having to write same methods over and over again, but what happens if the user adds something new to his library that I dont have a class/table for.

Comment: These classes can be auto generated as well. You can make the auto generation part of the build process so that your build is always compatible with the database the build is targeted for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something which is called [STI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Table_Inheritance): single table inheritance. It is suited to places like this, i guess, where a number of attributes are shared, and some are seperate.

So you could create a table, call it `LibraryItem`, and it has a type, which could be `CD, book, dvd` and a title, and some fields that will be filled in for some type and empty for others.

Normally it is best to create seperate tables for each, but sometimes the STI approach is more flexible. You can easily add a new type: e.g. LP or VHS, as long as it does not introduce too much new attributes/fields.